# How to disable the GUI in order to run the C++ program via SSH?

Tags: c++, linux, user-interface, ssh, terminal

I'm trying to run this [program](https://github.com/groupgets/GetThermal) remotely via SSH, but since it has a GUI, I get the error: "Could not connect to any X display."

I don't need the GUI, since I made some adaptions and want to experiment with it. I'm very new to programming, especially in C++.

So far, I tried to solve the problem, by removing/commenting the lines related to the uvcvideoproducer in the main.cpp and compiling it again, but it's still looking for a display and doesn't start via SSH.

When I entered the command "export DISPLAY=:0" in the command line first, then trying to run the programm, I get the output: "No protocol specified
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0
Could not connect to any X display."

I really don't know where to continue from here in order to solve the issue I'm having.

Thanks a lot, in advance for any help! It's very appreciated!

Comment: You could use ssh -X to allow the programm to be shown on your computer.

Comment: Instead of SSH, you could use the X protocol's support for remote display. Alternatively, you could rewrite the program to support remote sensing (and since you don't care about a GUI, just process the remotely sensed temperature data as you see fit).

Comment: I'm not super familiar with QT, but perhaps you could replace `QGuiApplication` with `QCoreApplication` since you don't need a GUI

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your responses!

The thing about ssh -X is, my colleague said, it's sometimes not even working between different distributions, and I'm even using Windows to connect to Ubuntu Server on a Raspberry Pi. So sorry for not adding this important information into my original post.

I actually solved my problem by using the [Xvfb](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml) library in order to simulate a display.

The only things I had to do are first installing it:

`sudo apt-get install xvfb`

And then run the program via the xvfb command:

`xvfb-run -a --server-args='-screen 0, 160x120x16' ./GetThermal`

I could also use a simulated display in the size of 1024x768x16 and probably many more formats, I just didn't notice any performance difference, when I was running it.